# Jackson Generic Type References + enableDefaultTyping issue

Tags: java, json, generics, jackson

I encountered an deserialization issue when using both enableDefaultTyping and providing a generic TypeRefernce. It seems that Jackson is unable to decide which type information is more important. This Test case is demonstarting the problem:

```
@Test
public void roundTripTest() throws JsonGenerationException,
        JsonMappingException, IOException {

    // 0 Value Test
    Integer[] integers = new Integer[] {};
    Wrap<Integer[]> beforeResult = new Wrap<Integer[]>(integers);

    File file = new File("/tmp/jsonTest");
    mapper.writeValue(file, beforeResult);

    TypeReference<Wrap<Integer[]>> typeRef = new TypeReference<JacksonMapperTest.Wrap<Integer[]>>() {
    };

    Wrap<Integer[]> afterResult = mapper.readValue(file, typeRef);

    assertNotNull(afterResult);

}


public static class Wrap<T> {

    private T wrapped;

    public Wrap() {
    }

    public Wrap(T wrapped) {
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
    }

    public T getWrapped() {
        return wrapped;
    }

    public void setWrapped(T wrapped) {
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
    }
}
```

where mapper is :

```
mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enableDefaultTyping();
```

and the exception is:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class JacksonMapperTest$Wrap<[Ljava.lang.Integer;>]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)
```

pretty weird, eh? by using beforeResult.getClass instead of TypeRefernce it is possible to omit the issue, but it is still not the prefered behavior.

Did I miss any kind of options in order to solve this?

I was using Jackson 1.9.3

[EDIT]
Using Maps Instead of an Array as Wrapped Objects works as expected!

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a bug in jackson...however its author is probably more competent to tell if it is a bug or not... if you are free to change from jackson take a look at genson http://code.google.com/p/genson/.

Gensons equivalent of enableDefaultTyping is setUseRuntimeTypeForSerialization (not exactly the same but it is very similar in most cases). It uses the runtime type during serialization. Here is an example:

```
Genson genson = new Genson.Builder().setUseRuntimeTypeForSerialization(true).create();
String json = genson.serialize(beforeResult);
System.out.println(json);
GenericType<Wrap<Integer[]>> type = new GenericType<Wrap<Integer[]>>() {};
Wrap<Integer[]> afterResult = genson.deserialize(json, type);
```

**EDIT**
If you need to be able to deserialize to polymoprhic or unknown types with genson use setWithClassMetadata(true) of Genson.Builder. This feature actually is used only for json objects (no matter if it is an abstract class or not).

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure of exact root cause, but I suspect this has to do with Java type erasure, and problems from passing generics-aware information and mixing it with default type information. Type info is actually only based on non-generic types; however, it does work for specific kinds of generic types (Maps, Collections).

But in this case you have custom generic type; and I think this is what makes Jackson unable to indicate generic type of property for purposes of dynamic typing.

The usual workaround is to try sub-classing if possible; but fortunately you were able to find a better workaround.